# Is it possible to test .NET Framework project with xUnit .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, xunit, .net-framework-version

I have an ASP.NET Framework v4.5.2 project. Can I use xUnit with .NET Core v2.0 to test it?

If yes, is it recommended?

If not, what alternatives I have?

Comment: yes, you can. yes, its recommended. go ahead. find out more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063306/how-do-i-create-net-framework-4-6-version-of-xunit-project-in-visual-studio-201

Answer (score 1):

No,

If the application references things like "System.Windows.Forms" - the .netcore Unit Test project won't be able to load it.

We just ran into this issue- and are converting our .netcore unit test project to match the .net 4.5.2 of our production assemblies.

Comment: But if you are testing an class that references System.Windows.Forms it is a application layer. It is not recomended to unit test app layer.