# How do I create .NET framework 4.6 version of XUnit project in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xunit, visual-studio-2019

I notice when I start up Visual Studio 2019, I am unable to create a .NET Framework version of XUnit or NUnit (only MSTests). We have been mandated to use XUnit tests, but our solution is all .NET Framework. Some of the nuget packages are dependent on being .NET Framework (for Sitecore 8.2) and thus I can't add them to a .NET Core project. I cannot upgrade any of the legacy project to .NET Core or to Sitecore 9+ at this time.

How do I add in a .NET Framework XUnit project? Is there something wrong with my Visual Studio setup? Is it not supported? I have been unable to find documentation from Microsoft about this. Thanks.

Comment: Just create a library project. Please refer to xUnit's own docs - https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/netfx/visual-studio

Comment: Matt's approach is probably easier :)

Comment: Was still a good suggestion. :)

Comment: Actually, it turns out that Matt's suggestion did not work for me; I had to create a Class Library project as the docs (and @StephenKennedy) suggested.  FWIW I had a requirement to target .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: @StephenKennedy i suggest you make your comment an answer. It is my prefered solution to the problem/question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

- First use the `xUnit Test Project (.NET Core)` project template.
- Then go edit the .csproj file and change `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>`.
- That's it. :)

Comment: Nice workaround, I miss the old-fashioned, "just pick this option when creating the project".

Comment: An official list of target framework monikers is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)

Answer (score 14):

- Install the `xUnit Test Project Template for .net framework` from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsakamoto.xUnitTestProjectTemplate).
- Create a new `xUnit Test Project (.NET Framework)` project
  [image]

Comment: This is the real answer as of today. No hack required like editing the project file.

Comment: @RBT, I don't consider a hack, I believe installing a special template for an older tech, that is not easily upgradable, is more of a hack. This is coming from someone who still works with 4.8 and appreciates the Framework support in most of the new DotNet ecosystem.